# How to get the values of parameters in Json?

Tags: c#

It's my first time doing this and chatGPT is unable to help me... I have this string API response that I convert in Json and I am trying to get the values of 2 of the parameters there.

This is how the string looks like:

```
{
    "offers": [
      {
        "order_hash": "0x630660fadfcd9b4f0b355f8a2a1bdc589e283407375d73fc7671aba17543f5fc",
        "chain": "ethereum",
        "price": {
          "currency": "WETH",
          "decimals": 18,
          "value": "14400000000000000"
        },
        "criteria": {
          "collection": {
            "slug": "flowerlolita-collections"
          },
          "contract": {
            "address": "0x81d8e220a6240d1b6dc42d13ed7e0316aa89f265"
          },
          "trait": null,
          "encoded_token_ids": "*"
        },
        "protocol_data": {
          "parameters": {
            "offerer": "0x71b7f0c5f064dd4278feb6a8f732f7167df3ed27",
            "offer": [
              {
                "itemType": 1,
                "token": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
                "identifierOrCriteria": "0",
                "startAmount": "14400000000000000",
                "endAmount": "14400000000000000"
              }
            ],
//more code
```

What I am looking for is to get the value of "offerer", in this case "0x71b7f0c5f064dd4278feb6a8f732f7167df3ed27" and the value of "startAmount", in this case "14400000000000000".

This is the code I have:

```
 public static double MyMethod(string apiResponse, string specificAddress)
        {
            JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(apiResponse);

            var specificOffererOffers = jsonResponse["offers"]
                .Where(offer =>
                    (string)offer["protocol_data"]["parameters"]["offerer"] == specificAddress &&
                    offer["protocol_data"]["parameters"]["offer"] != null &&
                    offer["protocol_data"]["parameters"]["offer"][0]["startAmount"] != null)
                .Select(offer =>
                {
                    double startAmount = double.Parse(offer["protocol_data"]["parameters"]["offer"][0]["startAmount"].ToString());
                    return startAmount;
                });

            if (!specificOffererOffers.Any())
            {
                return 0; // Return 0 if there are no offers with the specified address
            }

            double highestStartAmount = specificOffererOffers.Max();
            double highestValueInEther = highestStartAmount / Math.Pow(10, 18); // Convert to ether
            double roundedValue = Math.Round(highestValueInEther, 4);

            return roundedValue;
        }
```

When I call the method and give "0x71b7f0c5f064dd4278feb6a8f732f7167df3ed27" it returns 0.

Solution: The script works fine, the issue was that when comparing the offerer address and the address I give they are the same but one is with capital letters and one is not.

Comment: can you verify at runtime with the debugger active if the `jsonResponse` object is actually valued so that it match those conditions in the where clause? you may also simplify the strategy so that instead of using `where` and `select`you can actually loop through the array and see what's going on live

Comment: Why don't you just deserialize into a proper object model?

Comment: Diego, I did simplfy the strategy as you suggested and found out what the issue is. It's the dumbest thing ever - when comparing the offerer address and the address I give they are the same but one is with capital letters and one is not. I can't believe it I wasted so much time for this. Well I guess it's my first and last time. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the comments before, that an object model would be the better approach, I just made you a minimum working example from your JSON and code and with your approach to access the JSON using Newtonsoft.Json. The "offers" layer is stripped in the example for simplicity. I was curious in your usage of JObject and hope it helps you!

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = TestMethod("{\"protocol_data\": {\"parameters\": {\"offerer\": \"0xa07dc7def484eec683cc30ca437ad8839d1f7260\", \"offer\": [ {\"startAmount\": \"14400000000000000\"} ] }}}");
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        var number = double.Parse(result.startAmount);
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    
    public static (string offerer, string startAmount) TestMethod(string apiResponse)
    {
        JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(apiResponse);

        var offerer = jsonResponse["protocol_data"]["parameters"]["offerer"];
        var startAmount = jsonResponse["protocol_data"]["parameters"]["offer"][0]["startAmount"];
        
        return (offerer.ToString(), startAmount.ToString());
    }   
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
(0xa07dc7def484eec683cc30ca437ad8839d1f7260, 14400000000000000)
14400000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this. The issue is already fixed, I left a comment explaining and edited my post providing what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument`.

```
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
var startAmounts =
        doc.RootElement
            .GetProperty("offers")
            .EnumerateArray()
            .Select(x => x
                .GetProperty("protocol_data")
                .GetProperty("parameters"))
            .Where(x => x
                .GetProperty("offerer")
                .GetString() == "0x71b7f0c5f064dd4278feb6a8f732f7167df3ed27")
            .SelectMany(x => x
                .GetProperty("offer")
                .EnumerateArray()
                .Select(x => decimal.Parse(x
                    .GetProperty("startAmount")
                    .GetString())))
            .ToList();
```